# How to connect midi receiver to output its data?

Tags: java, midi

I am trying to write a small code which will take midi input from my piano and output the note information every time I press a key to the console. So far, I have gotten the code to list the available MIDI devices, and connect to the device's transmitter which then sends the information to the receiver.

How do I get this data (of the MIDI note) displayed to the console and constantly refreshing? I was thinking of using a while loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.sound.midi.InvalidMidiDataException;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiDevice;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.midi.Receiver;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequence;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequencer;
import javax.sound.midi.Track;
import javax.sound.midi.Transmitter;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine.Info;

public class Get {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MidiUnavailableException, InvalidMidiDataException, InterruptedException{
        javax.sound.midi.MidiDevice.Info[] infos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
        System.out.println("Select Midi Device Number:");
        for(int i=0;i<infos.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Device Number " + i + ": " + infos[i].getName() + " - " + infos[i].getDescription());
        }
        System.out.println("Enter device number then press enter...");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int deviceNumber = in.nextInt();
        MidiDevice input1Device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(infos[deviceNumber]);
        MidiDevice inputDevice = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(infos[deviceNumber]);
        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        Transmitter trans = inputDevice.getTransmitter();
        trans.setReceiver(MidiSystem.getReceiver());
        Receiver rec = trans.getReceiver();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a transmitter has a message, it calls the `send()` method of all connected receivers. So to get the message, you have to implement your own class that implemenets the `Receiver` interface.

See the example program [Listens to a MIDI port and dump the received event to the console](http://www.jsresources.org/examples/MidiInDump.html).